# eclipse-installer on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, eclipse

Has anybody tried to install a recent eclipse version using the eclipse-installer and not the manual installation?
How long does it run, it seems to take really long?
Does it work at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed Eclipse MARs via the installer only from eclipse.org

[image]

You can try this [link](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/mars/R1a/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz) if you have Ubuntu 64 bit

It's a tar.gz file(eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz)...takes less than 10 minutes on a decent internet connection(I have chosen the nearest mirror site)...you need to unzip it and then run the installer. It asks which variant to install(for Java or Java EE etc...) and for the path where to install. Finally installation is done -it can read the environment properties properly and thus set the installed JRE also based on the environment settings.

Once installation is done then you can bring the ICON on the sidebar for easy launch.

Comment: thanks, the tar.gz is already installed and unzipped. After selecting the variant and the installation path the installer seems to run forever and just tells me that it`s installing. I hope that made my question clearer.

Comment: Installer does download files during installation time..check connection and also the path where you are writing do you have all the access permission and does it writing anything out there?

Comment: There are a few problems with the files that are downloaded. I have to fix these and try again.

Comment: Ok it worked now, all I did was updating the installer.